# Angular6 - Jasmine: Test service without using a component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular6

I have a service which gets injected in the AppModule and is a singleton, and it uses a swagger-generated API service:

```
export class QueryService {

    public cache: Map<string, EvaluationResult> = new Map<string, EvaluationResult>();

    constructor(
        private queryService: QueryApi,
    ) { }

    public hashQueries(queries: Query[]): string {
        const hashedQueries: string[] = [];
        for (const query of queries) {
            hashedQueries.push(query.hashCode());
        }
        hashedQueries.sort();
        const hashcode = new Md5();
        hashcode.appendStr(hashedQueries.join(","));
        return (hashcode.end() as string);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this service uses a cache. Every query gets saved into the cache, using a hashcode, and when the method gets called, I check whether the query already exists in the cache.

I want to write a test that checks whether the hashcode function works. Currently I have something like this:

```
describe("QueryService", () => {

    it("should return a valid hashcode", () => {
        // make one type of query
        // make another type of query
        let service: QueryService;
        const queries = [attributeQuery, sodQuery];
        const hashcode = service.hashQueries(queries);
        expect(hashcode).toBeDefined();
        expect(hashcode.length).toBe(32);
    });

    it("should return the same hashcode", () => {
        // make two types of queries again but place them
        // in a different order
    });
    it("should return a different hashcode", () => {
        // make two types of queries again but change a
        // tiny detail so the hashcode is different
    });
}
```

As you can see, I want to use the QueryService, and it's hashQueries() function, without really needing a component. Initializing such a service isn't ideal, since it's constructor requires another API service, which requires other parameters as well.

Is there an easy way to make use of this service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should consider mocking the service `QueryApi`. And also I do not see any usage of the instance of `QueryApi` as well.

Comment: @AmitChigadani The QueryApi sends the requests to the server. I don't need that functionality here since I only wanna test the hash function. But it is needed to initiate a QueryService object

Comment: If you don't need that, then simply pass null to your constructor

Comment: @AmitChigadani Sigh... I really didn't think about that, how embarrassing! Thanks!

Comment: Also curious, Where is your `TesBed` configuration of service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to worry about `Dependency Injectors` of `service` unless you need them in your test spec. And you need not create `service` object using `new` operator.

You may do it as follows in your spec, which will eliminate the need of `DI` params :

`TestBed.get(QueryService)`

```
describe("QueryService", () => {
   let service : QueryService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [QueryService]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(QueryService);
    });

    it("should return a valid hashcode", () => {
        // make one type of query
        // make another type of query
        // let service: QueryService;          ---  No need to create service reference or object everytime
        const queries = [attributeQuery, sodQuery];
        const hashcode = service.hashQueries(queries);
        expect(hashcode).toBeDefined();
        expect(hashcode.length).toBe(32);
    });
}
```

Also

If you do not care about the `Dependency Injectors` of `service`, then you could simply pass `null` as a `constructor` parameter while creating an instance using `new` operator.

```
let service = new QueryService(null);
```